# Ajax in php is not working

Tags: php, ajax

/*
In the following code there is a dropdownlist, that has to call the function on every change has occurred to it.
This function name is TotalCountsOfPL().
And the drop down list is name and Id is "sltLeaveType";

After the function called a textbox(AjxSelectedLeaveType) should be filled with the selected value of the dropdownlist.

And the textbox(AjxTakenLeave) should be filled be filled with count which has been fetched by the database.

*/

I have the used the Ajax concept in my project.

That is on the change of Dropdownlist I am  calling the function(method). But this is not working.

Means when I select the content of dropdownList selected data(option) should be displayed in the text field called

my html file is 
I have the used the Ajax concept in my project.

That is on the change of Dropdownlist I am  calling the function(method). But this is not working.

my html file is

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function TotalCountsOfPL(str)
    {   
        if(iset(session_unregister("mySessionVariable")))
        {
            session_destroy();
        };       
        session_start();
        session_register("mySessionVariable");
        if(str!="")
        {
            $_SESSION["mySessionVariable"] = str;           
            document.getElementById("AjxSelectedLeaveType").innerHTML=str;
        }
        if (str=="")
        {
          document.getElementById("AjxTakenLeave").innerHTML="";
          //document.getElementById("AjxLeaveType").innerHTML="";
          return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("AjxTakenLeave").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","getPLCount.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
}

$prevEmployeeId= (isset($_POST['cmbEmployeeId'])) ? $_POST['cmbEmployeeId'] : "";
$prevLeaveFromDate = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveFromDate'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveFromDate'] : "";
$prevLeaveToDate = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveToDate'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveToDate'] : "";
$prevLeaveType = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveType'] : "";
$prevToTime = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveToTime'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveToTime'] : "";+
// Gnanendra .. Here I have consider the variable  $prevFromTime as "Total days" selected by the dropdownlist
$prevFromTime = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveFromTime'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveFromTime'] : "";
//G Comment below
$prevTotalTime = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveTotalTime'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveTotalTime'] : "";

$prevComments = (isset($_POST['txtComments'])) ? $_POST['txtComments'] : "";

$timeElementClass = (!empty($prevLeaveFromDate) && ($prevLeaveFromDate == $prevLeaveToDate)) ?
                        "show" : "hide";

$AjxSelectedLeaveType=(isset($_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'] : "";
$AjxTakenLeave=(isset($_POST['AjxTakenLeave'])) ? $_POST['AjxTakenLeave'] : "";
?>


<form id="frmLeaveApp" name="frmLeaveApp" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?leavecode=Leave&amp;action=<?php 

echo $modifier; ?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token;?>" name="token" />
<?php if (isset($confirmDate)) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="confirmDate" value="<?php echo $prevLeaveFromDate; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>

    <?php if (isset($role)) { ?>
      <?php if(($role == authorize::AUTHORIZE_ROLE_ADMIN) || ($role == authorize::AUTHORIZE_ROLE_SUPERVISOR)){ ?>
        <label for="cmbEmployeeId"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_EmployeeName; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="cmbEmployeeId" id="cmbEmployeeId" value="<?php echo isset($prevEmployeeId) ? $prevEmployeeId : ""; ?>" />


        <div class="yui-ac" id="employeeSearchAC" style="float: left">
        <input name="txtEmployeeId" autocomplete="off" class="yui-ac-input" id="txtEmployeeId" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($empName) ? 

CommonFunctions::escapeHtml($empName) : ""; ?>" tabindex="2" onfocus="showAutoSuggestTip(this)" style="color: #999999" />
              <div class="yui-ac-container" id="employeeSearchACContainer" style="top: 28px; left: 10px;">
              <div style="display: none; width: 159px; height: 0px; left: 100em" class="yui-ac-content">
              <div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-hd"></div>
              <div class="yui-ac-bd">
                    <ul>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                     <div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-ft"></div>
                    </div>
                   <div style="width: 0pt; height: 0pt;" class="yui-ac-shadow"></div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear"/>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <label for="sltLeaveType"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_LeaveType; ?></label>
    <select name="sltLeaveType" id="sltLeaveType" class="formSelect" onchange="TotalCountsOfPL(this.value)">
        <?php
            $skippedLeaveTypesCount = 0;

            if (is_array($records[1])) {
                foreach ($records[1] as $record) {
                    $className = get_class($record);

                    if ($className == 'LeaveQuota') {
                        if ($record->isLeaveQuotaDeleted()) {
                            $skippedLeaveTypesCount++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    $selected = ($record->getLeaveTypeID() == $prevLeaveType) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
        ?>
            <option <?php echo $selected;?> value="<?php echo $record->getLeaveTypeID();?>"><?php echo $record->getLeaveTypeName(); 

?></option>
            <?php       }

                        if ($skippedLeaveTypesCount == count($records[1])) { ?>
                                <option value="-1">-- <?php echo $lang_Error_NoLeaveTypes; ?> --</option>
                        <?php }
                } else { ?>
            <option value="-1">-- <?php echo $lang_Error_NoLeaveTypes; ?> --</option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br class="clear"/>
<!--Gnanendra Here the Leave date range will get-->
     <?php
        if (!(is_array($records[1])) && ($modifier == 'Leave_Apply')) {  ?>
            <div class="notice"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_LeaveQuotaNotAllocated; ?></div>
            <br class="clear"/>
     <?php } ?>

        <label for="txtLeaveFromDate"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromDate; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>

        <input name="txtLeaveFromDate" type="text" id="txtLeaveFromDate" size="10"
            value="<?php echo $prevLeaveFromDate; ?>" class="formDateInput"/>
          <input type="button" name="Submit" value="  " class="calendarBtn" id="btFromDate"/>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <label for="txtLeaveToDate"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_ToDate; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input name="txtLeaveToDate" type="text" id="txtLeaveToDate" size="10"
            value="<?php echo $prevLeaveToDate; ?>" class="formDateInput"/>

          <input type="button" name="Submit" value="  " class="calendarBtn" id="btToDate"/>
        <br class="clear"/>


      <div id="trTime1" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
       <label for="sltLeaveFromTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime; ?></label> 
    <?php $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime="Total Days"; ?>
    <label for="sltLeaveFromTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime; ?></label>
    <select name="sltLeaveFromTime" id="sltLeaveFromTime" onchange="fillTimes();"
                class="formTimeSelect"> 
        <select name="sltLeaveFromTime" id="sltLeaveFromTime" onchange="FillTheDayLength();"
                class="formTimeSelect">
            <option value=""></option>
            <!-- It will the time to the drop downlist (00:00 to 23:59) -->

            <?php
                for ($i=$startTime; $i<=$endTime; $i+=$interval) {
                    $timeVal = date('H:i', $i);
                    $selected = ($timeVal == $prevFromTime) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
            ?>
                    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $timeVal; ?>" ><?php echo LocaleUtil::getInstance()->formatTime($timeVal); 

?></option>
            <?php } ?>

           </select>

        <label for="sltLeaveToTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_ToTime; ?></label>
        <select name="sltLeaveToTime" id="sltLeaveToTime" onchange="fillTimes();"
                class="formTimeSelect">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                for ($i=$startTime; $i<=$endTime; $i+=$interval) {
                    $timeVal = date('H:i', $i);
                    $selected = ($timeVal == $prevToTime) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";

                ?>
                    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $timeVal; ?>" ><?php echo LocaleUtil::getInstance()->formatTime($timeVal); 

?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <label for="txtLeaveTotalTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_TotalHours; ?></label>
        <input name="txtLeaveTotalTime" id="txtLeaveTotalTime" size="4" onchange="fillTimes();"
                value="<?php echo $prevTotalTime; ?>" class="formInputText" style="width:3em;"/>

        <br class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div id="trTime2" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
      </div>

      <div id="trTime3" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">

      </div>
      <div id="trTime4" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
      </div>
      <br class="clear"/>
      <label for="txtComments"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_Comment; ?></label>
      <textarea name="txtComments" id="txtComments" class="formTextArea" rows="3" cols="20"
        ><?php echo $prevComments;?></textarea>


<!-- -->


        <input name="AjxSelectedLeaveType" type="text" id="AjxSelectedLeaveType" size="30"
            value="<?php (isset($_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'] : "Leave Type";?>" class="formDateInput"/>

         <input name="AjxTakenLeave" type="text" id="AjxTakenLeave" size="30"
            value="<?php (isset($_POST['AjxTakenLeave'])) ? $_POST['AjxTakenLeave'] : "Taken Leave";?>" class="formDateInput"/>

<!-- -->
      <br class="clear"/>
        <div class="formbuttons">
            <input type="button" class="<?php echo $btnClass;?>" id="saveBtn"
                onclick="addSave();" onmouseover="moverButton(this);" onmouseout="moutButton(this);"
                value="<?php echo $btnTitle;?>" title="<?php echo $btnTitle;?>"/>
        </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>


And the Following is getPLCount.php


<?php

$q=$_POST["AjxSelectedLeaveType"];

$Eid=$_SESSION["mySessionVariable"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'gnuser', 'anu123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("My_Database", $con);

$EmployeeId= $q;

if (isset($q))
{
    $query = "select count(leave_request_id) from leave_requests
where leave_type_id='LTY002' AND employee_id=".$q.";";
}
if(isset($Eid))
{
    $query = "select count(leave_request_id) from leave_requests
where leave_type_id='LTY002' AND employee_id=".$Eid.";";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "document.getElementById("AjxTakenLeave").innerHTML={$result}";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Please any one tell me why its not working.

Comment: Could you format your code? It's absolutely unreadable. Sighs...

Comment: i started editing then changed my mind, you have included too much code, revise it and only show the part that is concerned

Comment: paste you code on http://www.ideone.com an refer the link only and describe the error you are getting. nobody will took interest to see such lengthy code.

Comment: I thought If I provide all the (full) code, that will help to understand.

Comment: Use a JS console and see what's failing there, I suspect (but going to all that code is confusing and it's early in the morning here) the mixing of php and js there is far from optimal (take for example the session calls,`$_SESSION["mySessionVariable"]` should be echoed, and so on.. )

Comment: Unless you've got an extremely good reason not to (and I don't think you do), use a library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to implement your AJAX.  Dealing with the cross browser compatibility issues is a PITA, but it's a solved problem and there's no need for you to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, Where I can get the JS console. Should i install any external software.

Comment: @Indu Download and install Firebug extension for firefox, or access the developers tools in IE9 (press F12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing PHP with JavaScript. Here for example:

```
 if(str!="")
        {
            $_SESSION["mySessionVariable"] = str;           
            document.getElementById("AjxSelectedLeaveType").innerHTML=str;
        }
```

`$_SESSION` is PHP and `document.getElementById` is JavaScript.

Javascript is executed on the client side (ie: the broweser) and PHP is executed on your server. You can not mix them like that.

Comment: Will this work  if(str!="")
{
      <?php $_SESSION["mySessionVariable"] ?>= str;
         document.getElementById("AjxSelectedLeaveType").innerHTML=str;
        }

Comment: No, it won't - `str` is a js variable, `$_SESSION["mySessionVariable"]` is a PHP one. The `$_SESSION` variable will  will be evaluated by PHP and its **value** will reach in your HTML. So, in your HTML you will have something like  `if(str!="") { toto  = str; document.getElementById("AjxSelectedLeaveType").innerHTML=str; }`. 
Where `toto` is the value held in `$_SESSION["mySessionVariable"]`. Although, it might work - depending on what you intend

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting an error TotalCountsOfPL function, I think (correct me if mistaken) you are trying to use PHP functions inside Javascript function. Namely session functions. It is not legal. I also noticed a syntax error in your code, after body tag there is a php tag opening right after it there is a } but its not opened anywhere in php context. I recommend you to set display errors to true and also use a javascript debugger, like firebug or dragonfly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function TotalCountsOfPL(str)
    {   
        if(iset(session_unregister("mySessionVariable")))
        {
            session_destroy();
        };       
        session_start();
        session_register("mySessionVariable");
        if(str!="")
        {
            $_SESSION["mySessionVariable"] = str;           
            document.getElementById("AjxSelectedLeaveType").innerHTML=str;
        }
        if (str=="")
        {
          document.getElementById("AjxTakenLeave").innerHTML="";
          //document.getElementById("AjxLeaveType").innerHTML="";
          return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("AjxTakenLeave").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","getPLCount.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php


$prevEmployeeId= (isset($_POST['cmbEmployeeId'])) ? $_POST['cmbEmployeeId'] : "";
$prevLeaveFromDate = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveFromDate'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveFromDate'] : "";
$prevLeaveToDate = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveToDate'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveToDate'] : "";
$prevLeaveType = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveType'] : "";
$prevToTime = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveToTime'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveToTime'] : "";+
// Gnanendra .. Here I have consider the variable  $prevFromTime as "Total days" selected by the dropdownlist
$prevFromTime = (isset($_POST['sltLeaveFromTime'])) ? $_POST['sltLeaveFromTime'] : "";
//G Comment below
$prevTotalTime = (isset($_POST['txtLeaveTotalTime'])) ? $_POST['txtLeaveTotalTime'] : "";

$prevComments = (isset($_POST['txtComments'])) ? $_POST['txtComments'] : "";

$timeElementClass = (!empty($prevLeaveFromDate) && ($prevLeaveFromDate == $prevLeaveToDate)) ?
                        "show" : "hide";

$AjxSelectedLeaveType=(isset($_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'] : "";
$AjxTakenLeave=(isset($_POST['AjxTakenLeave'])) ? $_POST['AjxTakenLeave'] : "";
?>


<form id="frmLeaveApp" name="frmLeaveApp" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?leavecode=Leave&amp;action=<?php 

echo $modifier; ?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token;?>" name="token" />
<?php if (isset($confirmDate)) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="confirmDate" value="<?php echo $prevLeaveFromDate; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>

    <?php if (isset($role)) { ?>
      <?php if(($role == authorize::AUTHORIZE_ROLE_ADMIN) || ($role == authorize::AUTHORIZE_ROLE_SUPERVISOR)){ ?>
        <label for="cmbEmployeeId"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_EmployeeName; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="cmbEmployeeId" id="cmbEmployeeId" value="<?php echo isset($prevEmployeeId) ? $prevEmployeeId : ""; ?>" />


        <div class="yui-ac" id="employeeSearchAC" style="float: left">
        <input name="txtEmployeeId" autocomplete="off" class="yui-ac-input" id="txtEmployeeId" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($empName) ? 

CommonFunctions::escapeHtml($empName) : ""; ?>" tabindex="2" onfocus="showAutoSuggestTip(this)" style="color: #999999" />
              <div class="yui-ac-container" id="employeeSearchACContainer" style="top: 28px; left: 10px;">
              <div style="display: none; width: 159px; height: 0px; left: 100em" class="yui-ac-content">
              <div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-hd"></div>
              <div class="yui-ac-bd">
                    <ul>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                     <div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-ft"></div>
                    </div>
                   <div style="width: 0pt; height: 0pt;" class="yui-ac-shadow"></div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear"/>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <label for="sltLeaveType"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_LeaveType; ?></label>
    <select name="sltLeaveType" id="sltLeaveType" class="formSelect" onchange="TotalCountsOfPL(this.value)">
        <?php
            $skippedLeaveTypesCount = 0;

            if (is_array($records[1])) {
                foreach ($records[1] as $record) {
                    $className = get_class($record);

                    if ($className == 'LeaveQuota') {
                        if ($record->isLeaveQuotaDeleted()) {
                            $skippedLeaveTypesCount++;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    $selected = ($record->getLeaveTypeID() == $prevLeaveType) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
        ?>
            <option <?php echo $selected;?> value="<?php echo $record->getLeaveTypeID();?>"><?php echo $record->getLeaveTypeName(); 

?></option>
            <?php       }

                        if ($skippedLeaveTypesCount == count($records[1])) { ?>
                                <option value="-1">-- <?php echo $lang_Error_NoLeaveTypes; ?> --</option>
                        <?php }
                } else { ?>
            <option value="-1">-- <?php echo $lang_Error_NoLeaveTypes; ?> --</option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br class="clear"/>
<!--Gnanendra Here the Leave date range will get-->
     <?php
        if (!(is_array($records[1])) && ($modifier == 'Leave_Apply')) {  ?>
            <div class="notice"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_LeaveQuotaNotAllocated; ?></div>
            <br class="clear"/>
     <?php } ?>

        <label for="txtLeaveFromDate"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromDate; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>

        <input name="txtLeaveFromDate" type="text" id="txtLeaveFromDate" size="10"
            value="<?php echo $prevLeaveFromDate; ?>" class="formDateInput"/>
          <input type="button" name="Submit" value="  " class="calendarBtn" id="btFromDate"/>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <label for="txtLeaveToDate"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_ToDate; ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input name="txtLeaveToDate" type="text" id="txtLeaveToDate" size="10"
            value="<?php echo $prevLeaveToDate; ?>" class="formDateInput"/>

          <input type="button" name="Submit" value="  " class="calendarBtn" id="btToDate"/>
        <br class="clear"/>


      <div id="trTime1" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
       <label for="sltLeaveFromTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime; ?></label> 
    <?php $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime="Total Days"; ?>
    <label for="sltLeaveFromTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_FromTime; ?></label>
    <select name="sltLeaveFromTime" id="sltLeaveFromTime" onchange="fillTimes();"
                class="formTimeSelect"> 

            <option value=""></option>
            <!-- It will the time to the drop downlist (00:00 to 23:59) -->

            <?php
                for ($i=$startTime; $i<=$endTime; $i+=$interval) {
                    $timeVal = date('H:i', $i);
                    $selected = ($timeVal == $prevFromTime) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";
            ?>
                    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $timeVal; ?>" ><?php echo LocaleUtil::getInstance()->formatTime($timeVal); 

?></option>
            <?php } ?>

           </select>

        <label for="sltLeaveToTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_ToTime; ?></label>
        <select name="sltLeaveToTime" id="sltLeaveToTime" onchange="fillTimes();"
                class="formTimeSelect">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                for ($i=$startTime; $i<=$endTime; $i+=$interval) {
                    $timeVal = date('H:i', $i);
                    $selected = ($timeVal == $prevToTime) ? 'selected="selected"' : "";

                ?>
                    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value="<?php echo $timeVal; ?>" ><?php echo LocaleUtil::getInstance()->formatTime($timeVal); 

?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        <br class="clear"/>

        <label for="txtLeaveTotalTime"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_TotalHours; ?></label>
        <input name="txtLeaveTotalTime" id="txtLeaveTotalTime" size="4" onchange="fillTimes();"
                value="<?php echo $prevTotalTime; ?>" class="formInputText" style="width:3em;"/>

        <br class="clear"/>
      </div>
      <div id="trTime2" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
      </div>

      <div id="trTime3" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">

      </div>
      <div id="trTime4" class="<?php echo $timeElementClass;?>">
      </div>
      <br class="clear"/>
      <label for="txtComments"><?php echo $lang_Leave_Common_Comment; ?></label>
      <textarea name="txtComments" id="txtComments" class="formTextArea" rows="3" cols="20"
        ><?php echo $prevComments;?></textarea>


<!-- -->


        <input name="AjxSelectedLeaveType" type="text" id="AjxSelectedLeaveType" size="30"
            value="<?php (isset($_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'])) ? $_POST['AjxSelectedLeaveType'] : "Leave Type";?>" class="formDateInput"/>

         <input name="AjxTakenLeave" type="text" id="AjxTakenLeave" size="30"
            value="<?php (isset($_POST['AjxTakenLeave'])) ? $_POST['AjxTakenLeave'] : "Taken Leave";?>" class="formDateInput"/>

<!-- -->
      <br class="clear"/>
        <div class="formbuttons">
            <input type="button" class="<?php echo $btnClass;?>" id="saveBtn"
                onclick="addSave();" onmouseover="moverButton(this);" onmouseout="moutButton(this);"
                value="<?php echo $btnTitle;?>" title="<?php echo $btnTitle;?>"/>
        </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>


And the Following is getPLCount.php


<?php

$q=$_POST["AjxSelectedLeaveType"];

$Eid=$_SESSION["mySessionVariable"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'gnuser', 'anu123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("My_Database", $con);

$EmployeeId= $q;

if (isset($q))
{
    $query = "select count(leave_request_id) from leave_requests
where leave_type_id='LTY002' AND employee_id=".$q.";";
}
if(isset($Eid))
{
    $query = "select count(leave_request_id) from leave_requests
where leave_type_id='LTY002' AND employee_id=".$Eid.";";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "document.getElementById('AjxTakenLeave').innerHTML={$result}";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Hary, Please could you let me know where exactly you have changed the code.